SELinux enforcing mode with policy MLS. Fail "semodule -i" command
I have a server configured, previously without SELinux enabled.
I actived SELinux, configured it with SELinux users, etc. I enable the policy targeted and after change it to mls.
When I enabled the policy mls in permissive mode.
After of enable it, I relabeled the all labels doing:
fixfiles -F -v relabel

Then I after of a time doing tries and proofs, changed of permissive to enforcing and rebooted.
All good, but I saw that there are problems.

I try use the yum (yum update, yum install) not work. This doesn't have output.
I try install a SELinux module, with semodule -i and don't work. This show:

libsemanage.semanage_direct_install_file: Unable to read file podman-quadlet.pp
 (Permission denied).

The file has 644 permissions.

The command ip a not work.

My SELinux status is:
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             mls
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     denied
Memory protection checking:     actual (secure)
Max kernel policy version:      33

And configuration:
SELINUX=enforcing
SELINUXTYPE=mls

When the mode is permissive logically all work. But in mode enforcing not.
This looks like be a problem of labels relabeling.
This is not normal. Although the mode be enforcing. The tools semodule, ip, yum should work well. I understand.
I think that the problem is the relabeling. But I relabeled all. Believe...
Detail. If I execute:
fixfiles -F onboot

That generate /.autorelabel with content: -F. And I reboot.
The system relabel but cannot delete the /.autorelabel by which the system is restarted. The system be restart in loop.
Also, during the relabeling, there are path that is not possible relabel...
This show:
...
Warning no default label for /dev/mqueue
/sbin/setfiles: Could not set context for /opt/backups/system/boot/syslinux/ldlinux.sys:  Operation not permitted
...

This what means?
Someone know what happen? How to can I solve this?
Some idea?
Thanks
Greetings.
UPDATE 16/09/2024
I looking the official course of SELinux by Redhat (PDF: https://docs.redhat.com/en-us/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/pdf/using_selinux/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-9-Using_SELinux-en-US.pdf, web: https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/using_selinux/index).
There are a section that tells:

Users with top-level clearances do not automatically acquire administrative rights on multi-level
systems. While they might have access to all sensitive information about the system, this is different
from having administrative rights.
In addition, administrative rights do not provide access to sensitive information. For example, even when
someone logs in as root, they still cannot read top-secret information.

With this, I understand that if the user 'user1' that can scale privileges thanks a sudoers and change the SELinux role to sysadm_r
user1       ALL=(ALL)       TYPE=sysadm_t   ROLE=sysadm_r   ALL

The user scaled will not have all the permissions as if you had log in in a shell directly as root.
And some commands or processes not work.
My configuration of SELinux users and login are the following:
# semanage user -l

                Labelling  MLS/       MLS/                          
SELinux User    Prefix     MCS Level  MCS Range                          SELinux Roles

guest_u         user       SystemLow  SystemLow                      guest_r
root            user       SystemLow  SystemLow-SystemHigh           auditadm_r secadm_r staff_r sysadm_r system_r
staff_u         user       SystemLow  SystemLow-SystemHigh           auditadm_r secadm_r staff_r sysadm_r system_r
sysadm_u        user       SystemLow  SystemLow-SystemHigh           sysadm_r
system_u        user       SystemLow  SystemLow-SystemHigh           system_r
user_u          user       SystemLow  SystemLow                      user_r
xguest_u        user       SystemLow  SystemLow                      xguest_r
# semanage login -l

Login Name           SELinux User         MLS/MCS Range        Service

__default__          user_u               SystemLow            *
user1             staff_u              SystemLow-SystemHigh *

# cat /etc/sudoers.d/user1 
user1        ALL=(ALL)       TYPE=sysadm_t   ROLE=sysadm_r   ALL

With this configuration the user user1 can uses the sudo -i for scale privileges. This work.
I looked that if I log in me as root in the machine with ssh, the id -Z is root:sysadm_r:sysadm_t:SystemLow-SystemHigh.
And the session has permissions for execute for example ip a, semodule -i or yum
But if I am logged as user1 via SSH and elevate privileges with sudo the output of id -Z is staff_u:sysadm_r:sysadm_t:SystemLow-SystemHigh, but not can do ip a, semodule -i or yum.
I believe that this is the behavior normal with mls policy. What difference there are logging as root without ssh and elevating privileges with user1 via ssh?
If this is the behavior normal, is possible do that at elevate privileges the permissions would be the same that as root without ssh?
As "fix", as root with staff_u. At execute the command ip this fail. And I do: systemctl status setroubleshootd.service.
Where specific as solve it. Doing a policy customized with audit2allow. Doing this is "solved" even if I logged as user1 and elevate privileges.
But this is recommend and good proofs?
Thanks.
Grettings.
